# Save Plain Text to File (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, nssavepanel

My application (for Mac) generates some HTML... This HTML then needs to be saved to a .html file. I'm trying to use a NSSavePanel like this:

```
- (IBAction)saveFile:(id)sender{
    NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    [savePanel setRequiredFileType:@"html"];
    [savePanel setTitle:@"Save Code to File"];
    if ([savePanel runModal] == NSOKButton) 
    {
        [[_codeStore RTFFromRange:
          NSMakeRange(0, [[_codeStore string] length])] 
         writeToURL:[savePanel URL] atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"saved");
    }    
}
```

My problem is that this does not save is a plain text. For example, when I open the generated file in a web browser, the html shows up, but

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1157\cocoasubrtf700
>   {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
>   {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
>   \pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\pardirnatural
>   \f0\fs24 \cf0

is at the top of the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be

```
    [[_codeStore RTFFromRange: NSMakeRange(0, [[_codeStore string] length])]
     writeToURL: [savePanel URL]
     atomically: YES];
```

You're outputting an RTF document that contains the HTML. You need

```
    [[_codeStore string] writeToURL: [savePanel URL] 
                         atomically: YES
                           encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                              error: nil];
```

This will take the raw NSString from your NSAttributedString `_codeStore` and write that to a file.

Comment: This was correct, but I had to change NSUTF8Encoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: @MihirSingh thanks, updated. I always just type NSUTF8 and let Xcode do the rest!

Answer (score 0):

i think using rtf encoding is causing the problem since it can write beyond 8 bit using escape sequence. You may try to use simple nsstring way of writing to file.

```
BOOL ok = [string writeToFile:path atomically:YES

                  encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];
```